# Is there anyway to create face recognition and detection app using iPhone X ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, face-detection, iphone-x

I want to create an app where user first input his face and iPhone will capture that. Later, when the user again input his face iPhone will tell if its same real person or not. I also want to differentiate between 2D fake images and real human face? Can I do that with ARKit iPhone X or is there any-other way to do so? 
I am able to detect the face but don't know how to filter 2D fake images and real face and how to match.

Can I scan face through iPhone X and save the 3D image somewhere and then later on check and match again with that same 3D image using iPhone X?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is no api that provides direct access to the true depth camera.

Comment: I just checked. I can use ARKit to do that. But I don't know how do I first scan image and save it and then match it again. Any idea on that?

Comment: I doubt that the data from `ARFaceGeometry` will be sufficient to recognise a specific individual, although I guess you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to take a picture about the user's face, or faceID is enough?

Because you can use FaceID (or TouchID) in your app with
[TJBioAuthenticaiton](https://github.com/tejas-ardeshna/TJBioAuthentication)

Comment: I want to take a picture or some mechanism to match it against some face